# Dependency Injection: How to get access to the corresponding ProductView that executes the Command?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, command-pattern

I want to execute commands for each product view. Consider 10 products views, and each of them can execute the `PrintProductViewCommand`. This command, takes in constructor a `ProductView` and prints its name. Since it is `@Inject`able, the container will create a new ProductView each time the command is created. The following example shows what I want to do:

```
public class InjectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(ProductView.class);
                bind(CommandExecutor.class);
                bind(PrintProductViewNameCommand.class);
                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(ProductView.class, ProductView.class)
                        .build(ProductViewFactory.class));
            }
        });

        List<ProductView> productViews = new ArrayList<>();
        ProductViewFactory factory = injector.getInstance(ProductViewFactory.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            productViews.add(factory.create("Name: " + String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        System.out.println("Done creating");
        //Now sometime in future, each product view calls print method
        productViews.forEach(ProductView::print);
    }

    private static interface ProductViewFactory {
        ProductView create(String name);
    }

    private static class ProductView {
        private String name; //simulate a property
        private CommandExecutor executor;

        public ProductView() {
            //Guice throws exception when this is missing
            //Probably because it is being asked in PrintProductViewCommand
        }

        @AssistedInject
        public ProductView(@Assisted String name, CommandExecutor executor) {
            this.name = name;
            this.executor = executor;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        //assume some time product view it self calls this method
        public void print() {
            executor.execute(PrintProductViewNameCommand.class);
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    private static class CommandExecutor {
        @Inject
        private Injector injector;

        public void execute(Class<? extends Command> cmdType) {
            injector.getInstance(cmdType).execute();
        }
    }

    private static class PrintProductViewNameCommand implements Command {
        private ProductView view;

        @Inject
        public PrintProductViewNameCommand(ProductView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            //Want to print "Name: something" here
            System.out.println(view.getName());
        }

    }

    private static interface Command {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

This problem is solved if I add a parameter to Command interface, and make it `Command<T>`. Then `CommandExecutor` will have this method:

```
public <T> void execute(Class<? extends Command<T>> cmdType, T parameter) {
    injector.getInstance(cmdType).execute(parameter);
}
```

So, my `PrintProductViewNameCommand` is now `class PrintProductViewNameCommand implements Command<ProductView>`, and in product view :

```
public void print() {
    executor.execute(PrintProductViewNameCommand.class,this);
}
```

However, the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) has no parameter in `execute()`. I have also seen somewhere that adding a parameter is an anti-pattern.

Of course, the command is simple. Assume that the command has other dependencies too, like Services etc.

Is there a way I can achieve it? Perhaps I am doing something wrong, probably with the whole DI situation.

When not using dependency injection, I would do something like this:

```
ProductView view = new ProductView();
Command command = new PrintProductViewNameCommand(view);
view.setPrintCommand(command);
```

But how to it while using DI?

Comment: I think what might be complicated this the most is the circular dependency on the `ProductView` and the `PrintProductViewNameCommand`. I know this is a toy example but in your real application will it be 100% necessary for the `PrintProductViewNameCommand` to know about the `ProductView`?

Comment: @WilliamHammond Yes it will. The `command` depends on a variety of services and in the view. Passing the services into the view is a thing, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

So this works, although I'm not sure if it's 100% what you want to do.

```java
public class InjectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(CommandExecutor.class);
                bind(ProductView.class);
                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                        .implement(ProductView.class, ProductView.class)
                        .build(ProductViewFactory.class));

                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                        .implement(PrintProductViewNameCommand.class, PrintProductViewNameCommand.class)
                        .build(PrintProductViewNameCommand.Factory.class));
            }
        });

        ProductViewFactory factory = injector.getInstance(ProductViewFactory.class);
        List<ProductView> productViews = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            productViews.add(factory.create("Name: " + i));
        }
        System.out.println("Done creating");
        //Now sometime in future, each product view calls print method
        productViews.forEach(ProductView::print);
    }
    private interface ProductViewFactory {
        ProductView create(String name);
    }


    private static class ProductView {
        private String name;
        private CommandExecutor executor;
        private PrintProductViewNameCommand printProductViewNameCommand;

        @AssistedInject
        public ProductView(@Assisted String name, PrintProductViewNameCommand.Factory printProductViewNameCommandFactory, CommandExecutor executor) {
            this.name = name;
            this.executor = executor;
            this.printProductViewNameCommand = printProductViewNameCommandFactory.create(this);
        }

        public ProductView() {}

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        //assume some time product view it self calls this method
        public void print() {
            executor.execute(printProductViewNameCommand);
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    private static class CommandExecutor {
        public void execute(Command command) {
            command.execute();
        }
    }

    private static class PrintProductViewNameCommand implements Command {
        private final ProductView view;

        @AssistedInject
        public PrintProductViewNameCommand(@Assisted ProductView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        static interface Factory {
            PrintProductViewNameCommand create(ProductView productView);
        }

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            //Want to print "Name: something" here
            System.out.println(view.getName());
        }

    }

    private static interface Command {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

Basically what you're running into is a cyclic dependency problem (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CyclicDependencies#use-factory-methods-to-tie-two-objects-together) that's also exasperated by a bit by the fact that you have an additional `AssistedInject` in the `ProductView`.

By the way I'm using Guice 3 in this example.